# Make a list of firebase users

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a list of all my users from Firebase with their username.

[image: This is how my users is saved.]

My problem is that I am trying to make an array of all the users.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

var memberRef = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)/users")
//var currentUser = DataService.dataService.USER_REF.authData.uid



var currentUsers: [String] = [String]()

class dataTableView: UITableViewController
{

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        loadUsers()
    }

    func loadUsers()
    {
        // Create a listener for the delta additions to animate new items as they're added
        memberRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in

            print(currentUsers)

            // Add the new user to the local array
            currentUsers.append(snap.value as! String)

            // Get the index of the current row
            let row = currentUsers.count - 1

            // Create an NSIndexPath for the row
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)

            // Insert the row for the table with an animation
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Top)

        })
    }
```

But I get the error cant cast value of type NSDictionary to NSString.

Comment: Please paste your Firebase structure as text instead of a picture. You can get that using the Export button in the Firebase dashboard. Text will keep us from having to re-type the structure in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase snapshot is a dictionary, not a string which is why you are receiving that error.

To access the elements of the snapshot:

```
if let name = snapshot.value["name"] as? String {
   print(name)
}
```

you can also use

```
if let name = snapshot.value.objectForKey("name") as? String {
```